# Pytorch equivalent of TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to follow up on this code in Pytorch. I have been trying for days but reading tensor flow docs then PyTorch docs has made me totally confused.

```
input_data = Input(shape=(256, 64, 1), name=‘input’)

inner = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding=‘same’, name=‘conv1’, kernel_initializer=‘he_normal’)(input_data)
inner = BatchNormalization()(inner)
inner = Activation(‘relu’)(inner)
inner = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name=‘max1’)(inner)

inner = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding=‘same’, name=‘conv2’, kernel_initializer=‘he_normal’)(inner)
inner = BatchNormalization()(inner)
inner = Activation(‘relu’)(inner)
inner = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name=‘max2’)(inner)
inner = Dropout(0.3)(inner)

inner = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding=‘same’, name=‘conv3’, kernel_initializer=‘he_normal’)(inner)
inner = BatchNormalization()(inner)
inner = Activation(‘relu’)(inner)
inner = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 2), name=‘max3’)(inner)
inner = Dropout(0.3)(inner)

CNN to RNN
inner = Reshape(target_shape=((64, 1024)), name=‘reshape’)(inner)
inner = Dense(64, activation=‘relu’, kernel_initializer=‘he_normal’, name=‘dense1’)(inner)

RNN
inner = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True), name = ‘lstm1’)(inner)
inner = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True), name = ‘lstm2’)(inner)

OUTPUT
inner = Dense(num_of_characters, kernel_initializer=‘he_normal’,name=‘dense2’)(inner)
y_pred = Activation(‘softmax’, name=‘softmax’)(inner)

model = Model(inputs=input_data, outputs=y_pred)
```

I tried following up it in Pytorch, bit by bit

```
class Net(nn.Module):
def init(self):
super(Net,self).init()
self.input_data = input_size
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(32,3,3)
self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64,3,3)
self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(128,3,3)


self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
self.maxp = torch.nn.MaxPool2d((2,2))


#CNN to RNN
self.linear1 = nn.Linear(256*62*62,64)

#RNN
self.lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(256, 10,bidirectional = True)

#output
self.linear2 = nn.Linear(64,num_of_chars)

def forward(self,x,input_size):
    
     
    x = self.conv1(input_size)
    x = nn.BatchNorm2d(x)
    x = F.relu(x)
    x = self.maxp(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = nn.BatchNorm2d(x)
    x = F.relu(x)
    x = self.maxp(x)
    x = self.dropout(x)
    x = self.conv3(x)
    x = nn.BatchNorm2d(x)
    x = F.relu(x)
    x = self.maxp(x)
    x = self.dropout(x)
    x = x.view((64,1024))
    x = self.linear1(x)
    
    x = self.lstm(x)
    x = self.lstm(x)
    
    x = self.linear2(x)
    x = nn.Softmax(x,dim=1)
    return x
```

But the model summary is not at all same. I am very confused by the parameters. Any help would be appreciated. Tell me if you need anything. Thanks

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? The neural network is a chain of operations; every layer is the image of the previous layer by some operation. This translates to lines like `inner = Activation(‘relu’)(inner)` in one code, and `x = F.relu(x)` in the other.

Comment: I have trouble understanding how the input data works,i,e if their input = Input(shape=(256,64,1) then should I DO x = x.view(256,64,1) or something else. Also,In their case, lstm works normally, in Pytorch it asks for hidden dim !. More or less I am confused by the shape of the layers and the images

Comment: What is confusing about the shapes? Can you maybe give an example with a much smaller network? The current one has 20 functions chained one after the other. I suggest trying with 3 functions to begin with, and moving on to 20 when you're less confused. You didn't actually ask a question! You posted a fairly long code and a fairly long, supposedly equivalent code, and said you were confused.

Comment: ok, will take some time to figure it out